# Getting a toggle button on navbar to work

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am having trouble with a navbar when it's on tablet and mobile size. When I click on the dropdown button I need it to take up the whole page. Basically it has to take up the whole height when I click on the dropdown button for mobile or tablet. I think I need to use JavaScript for it but I don't know how exactly.

This is my navbar. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and also some CSS to edit it but I just need to somehow make it for tablet and mobile like I explained above.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-yellow px-5 py-3 font-weight-bold" id="navbar">
        <div class="logo d-flex flex-column">
          <a href="index.html" class="mx-auto"><img src="./Design/Logo.png"  width="40" height="40" class="logo-img"></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto font-weight-bold" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav w-90 justify-content-around ml-lg-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Academy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Academy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Academy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Academy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item justify-self-end">
                <a href="./contact.html" class="btn btn-danger">Button</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElfDx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBqys.png)

This is how its supposed to look like when clicked on the dropdown button when on tablet or mobile—basically it has to take up the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want the navbar to be full-height when the button is clicked. For that you'll need a javascript function:

```
<script>
    function toggleNav() {
        document.querySelector("#navbar").style.height = "100%"
        document.body.overflow = "hidden" // added this for making the page unscrollable.
    }
</script>
```

This script tag will be placed at bottom of the body tag. And what it basically does is giving `height: 100%;` to the `#navbar` when called.

Now we need to call the function when the button is clicked. So, we'll add `onclick="toggleNav();"` to the button. Like this:

```
<button onclick="toggleNav();" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

If you check your webpage now, you'll see that the `#navbar` DOES get the `height: 100%;` when the button is triggered. But you won't see anything happen, that is because our html tag's height is limited. So, lets fix that by adding these css codes:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: hii so i tried this and it actually didnt do anything? Do i not have an id for the navbar somewhere because it actually like didnt do anything...

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you exactly wanted. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Okay so you know how you have a navbar right? So when its on mobile theres like a hamburger logo or menu or whatever you wanna call it a toggle button. Okay so when i click the toggle button its supposed to make the navabar full-window size full height basically and when its clicked you cant like scroll down to the page. For ex: my page has a navbar banner footer etc.. so when i click the toggle button you cant actually scroll down to the banner or footer thats what i need. I think i need a command with js so that when i click on the toggle button all you can see is the navbar but full height.

Comment: i would send you my whole code but i cant here haha

Comment: i tried using 

.navbar-collapse.show, .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
  transition: height 0s ease;
 
}

.navbar-collapse.show {
  height: 100vh;
}

that worked but halfway because you can actually scroll down to the page which i dont want that.

Comment: i made it work somehow but only halfway i used

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {

  .filters {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 1em auto;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      max-width: 300px;
  }
  
.navbar-collapse.show, .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
  transition: height 0s ease;
}

.navbar-collapse.show {
  height: 100vh;
}

but you can still scroll down to the page... idk how to make it unscrollable or like fixed.

Comment: If you want to stop the user from scrolling, you should add "overflow: hidden" to the body, but not with css. Let me edit my answer (Sorry for the delay between my comments)

Answer (score 1):

From what I am able to understand you want the navbar to cover the entire screen by hiding the content.
In **bootstrap 5** there is **offcanvas** component for this functionality.

To implement similar functionality in **bootstrap 4** you would need to use **jQuery**.

Here is an to use off-canvas functionality in bootstrap 4.
Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fixHeight = function() {
    $('.navbar-nav').css(
      'max-height',
      document.documentElement.clientHeight - 150
    );
  };
  fixHeight();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    fixHeight();
  });
  $('.navbar .navbar-toggler').on('click', function() {
    fixHeight();
  });
  $('.navbar-toggler, .overlay').on('click', function() {
    $('.mobileMenu, .overlay').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .mobileMenu {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    transition: all ease 0.25s;
    &.open {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    .navbar-nav {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  }
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: none;
    &.open {
      display: block;
      z-index: 1029;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Off-canvas Sidebar Navigation For Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
  <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-L/W5Wfqfa0sdBNIKN9cG6QA5F2qx4qICmU2VgLruv9Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand order-1 order-lg-0 ml-lg-0 ml-2 mr-auto" href="#">jQueryScript</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-start" type="button">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-dark p-3 p-lg-0 mt-5 mt-lg-0 d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row flex-xl-row justify-content-lg-end mobileMenu" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-self-stretch">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 align-self-stretch">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container py-4 my-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Off-canvas Sidebar Navigation For Bootstrap 4</h1>
        <div id="carbon-block" style="margin:50px auto"></div>
        <div style="margin:50px auto">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-OUFW7hFO0/r5aEGTQOz9F/aXQOt+TwqI1Z4fbVvww04=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hii thanks for replying but i dont need something like this unfortunately, i need the navbar to be full-height when the button is clicked like someone said here.